# How can i get nodeList using xpath in Apache Camel

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I have an xml like

```
<Response>
    <Status>
        <Code>0</Code>
    </Status>
    <Order>
        <OrderId>1</OrderId>
    </Order>
</Response>
```

How can i get all the nodes instead Response, but without the  tag

When i try this, I get the entire xml

```
<xpath>/Response</xpath>
```

When i try this, the output is blank

```
<xpath>/Response/text()</xpath>
```

What can i do so I only get this, with the outer tag

```
   <Status>
        <Code>0</Code>
    </Status>
    <Order>
        <OrderId>1</OrderId>
    </Order>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if the desired output is the XML without the document element or if you want all of the text from within the XML.

If you want the sequence of child elements, then you would want:

```
/Response/*
```

If you want the You could use the [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string) function to get the computed text value of the `/Response` element:

```
string(/Response)
```

If that happens to include some unwanted carriage returns and whitespace, due to the XML being pretty-printed, you could use [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space), which will collapse repeated whitespace:

```
normalize-space(/Response)
```